# Prove $f(x)$ is a square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For my first part of my question, I have to prove that if $a$ is any integer and the polynomial $f(x) = x^2 +ax+ 1$ factors (mod 8), then $f(x)$ is in fact a square; so what that means is that $f(x) ≡ (x + c)^2$(mod 8) for some non-negative integer $c<8$.

Then my next part of my question is that what can be the possible values of a? Meaning that, for which non-negative $a$ less than 8 does $f(x)$ factor?

Comment: What's the definition of poly mod?

Comment: @GFauxPas polynomial mod

Comment: I figured as much, but what does that mean? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @GFauxPas Disregard the poly

Comment: Compute all possible expressions $(x+c)^2 \mod 8$ and keep the ones that give $x^2+ax+1$. Then look for an insight from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quadratic can only factor into linear terms, and since the linear coefficients here have to be units we can assume they are $1$.  So $x^2+ax+1 = (x+b)(x+c)$ with $bc=1$.  Modulo $8$ that means $b=c$ with $b$ odd.

Comment: So this proves that it is a square

Comment: It is a square if it factors at all.  And the the linear term of the quadratic is the double of a unit.

Comment: And what about the second part of my question

Comment: I already said, the possible values of $a$ are the doubles of units.  Mod 8 the units are 1,3,5,7 and their doubles are 2,6.

Comment: So the possible are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: The possible are the doubles of 1,3,5,7.  Those doubles are 2,6.

Comment: Oh okay so only 2 and 6 are possible

Answer (score 1):

If $x^2 + ax + 1$ factors working modulo 8, then it would have** to factor as

$$(x \pm b)(x \pm b^{-1})= (x^2 \pm b \pm b^{-1} + 1),$$
where $\pm(b + b^{-1}) = a$.

In other words, as long as you can express $a$ as a sum of multiplicative inverses (modulo 8), then your polynomial factors.

Your only invertible elements are 1, 3, 5, and 7, all of them are self-inverse. Thus, your possible $a$-values are twice these invertible elements; this would mean that $a \in \{2, 6\}$.

For those $a$-values, is your polynomial necessarily a square?

EDIT:** More generally, your polynomial may factor as
$$(bx + c)(b^{-1}x + c^{-1}) = x^2 + (bc^{-1} + cb^{-1})x + 1,$$ but the analysis above would remain largely the same, since $bc^{-1} = (cb^{-1})^{-1}$.